# sql оператор LIKE для выборки строк

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть "массив" значений: ("Изумруд","Фианит","Гранат","Раухтопаз")
В БД в поле vstavki значения представлены в виде строк:
    id  vstavki
    1   гранат, топаз, аметист, раухтопаз, хризолит
    2   london-топаз, фианит
    3   аметист, цитрин, гранат, топаз, фианит
    4   аметрин, фианит
    5   топаз, фианит
и т.д.
Как написать выражение для LIKE чтобы вывело все строки, в которых есть хотя бы одно слово представленное в массиве ?

Comment: `LIKE` не проверяет на вхождение подстроки, а не с регуляркой

Comment: Пишу  vstavki LIKE '%Изумруд%'  выводит все строки с "изумруд".
А как написать что- типа vstavki LIKE '%Изумруд%'OR'%Гранат%' ?

Comment: Это не регулярное выражение, это простое сравнение по шаблону. Регулярки вам тут не нужны

Answer (score 1):

Объедените через `OR`:

```
WHERE (vstavki LIKE "%изумруд%"
   OR vstavki LIKE "%фианит%"
   OR vstavki LIKE "%гранат%"
   OR vstavki LIKE "%раухтопаз%") AND...;
```

Собрать такую строку можно в любом ЯП.

А регулярка в мускуле это [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html).

Comment: SELECT * FROM price WHERE section = 1 AND size IN(17,16) AND price BETWEEN 5000 AND 19000 AND material IN('Серебро','Золото','Белое золото') AND vstavki LIKE '%Хризолит%' OR vstavki LIKE '%фианит%'
Если напишу так то благодаря OR игнорируются условия позади

Comment: @amijin так сгруппируйте все OR, возьмите в скобки

Comment: @amijin обновил ответ

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  price
WHERE section = 1
  AND size IN(17,16)
  AND price BETWEEN 5000 AND 10000
  AND material IN('Серебро','Золото','Белое золото')
HAVING vstavki LIKE '%Хризолит%' OR vstavki LIKE '%фианит%'
```

Нужно было использовать HAVING перед выборкой через LIKE

Comment: нет, достаточно группировку условий использовать. Знаете ведь чем отличается предикат WHERE от HAVING?

Comment: HAVING есть смысл только с GROUP BY, да даже и в этом случае - сначала выберется всё, проходящее под WHERE, потом только по всей полученной выборке пойдет фильтрация из HAVING. Медленная бессмыслица даже после правки.